# Python 3 type check not works with use typing module?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Why does type checking not work in Python 3?

I have done the following code with type checks or hints:

```
import typing

def hello(message: str):
    print(type(message))
    print(message)

hello('Hello!')
hello(1)
hello(1.1)
```

It produces valid output (but no errors on int or float).

```
<class 'str'>
Hello!
<class 'int'>
1
<class 'float'>
1.1
```

Why does it works this way? Maybe I don't understand the typing module and Python hints.

Comment: Thank you for all help - all answers are good - it is hard to choose one the best. Now I understand that hints can be use for validation if I do some decorator but normally it is nice hints to improve readability. Nice to see that mypy can use this information for static typing it shows new opportunity soon.

Comment: I believe you don't have to import `typing`.

Comment: The [documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is pretty misleading. By using terminology like `runtime support for type hints` it implies that this functionality actual _does something_. It doesn't. It's just empty syntax that allows the author to document their code in a systematic way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python's type hints are informational only. Type checking or automatic coercion of argument types are not part of the language. See [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#id29):

> Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at compile-time.

The type hints *could* be used by an add-on module to check the types of arguments and returned values, or even to coerce arguments to the expected type. For example, [here](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) is a module that will check argument types and complain if it finds a mismatch.

But this is not how Python itself works, so don't rely on it and don't look for ways to bring it into your code. In Python style, your functions should be written to be as flexible as possible about the argument types they can work with (google "duck typing"). If they get something they can't handle... well, that's what exceptions are for.

**Update:** The [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module, which provides support for type hints, was added to the standard library ("on a provisional basis") as of Python 3.5. It provides some useful type names including `Any`, `Callable` and `Union`, and a helper function `NewType`. Type hints remain very, very optional.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 doesn't have the kind of type checking you're looking for.

```
def hello(message: str):
```

This is a *function annotation*.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

All it does is associate a bit of extra data with the function object.  This can be inspected later on the `func_annotations` attribute of the function.

It has no built-in behavior beyond this.  The intent is for third-parties to build behavior on top of this.

Answer (score 2):

Type hints are just **hints**, they should tell users what the function **expects** not what it requires. This is explicitly mentioned in the PEP that introduced them: [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/):

> Fundamentals of Function Annotations
>
> Before launching into a discussion of the precise ins and outs of Python 3.0's function annotations, let's first talk broadly about what annotations are and are not:
>
> - Function annotations, both for parameters and return values, are completely optional.
> - Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at compile-time.
>
>   By itself, Python does not attach any particular meaning or significance to annotations. [...]

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `static typing`, which is opposite to `dynamic typing` paradigm accepted by python.

You may use [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org) - a project which brings static typing to python.

Answer (score 1):

They are called "Type Hints" for a reason. Python just gives the option to mark types in a standard and structured way, to guide other programmers or to facilitate IDE error checking.

However, Python doesn't enforce these Hints, nor there's any plan to, they are just that, not much more than comments.