# Mypy doesn't throw an error when mixing booleans with integers

Tags: python, integer, boolean, mypy

I am trying to use mypy to check a Python 3 project. In the example below, I want mypy to flag the construction of the class `MyClass` as an error, but it doesn't.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, i:int) -> None:
        pass

obj = MyClass(False)
```

Can anyone explain this, please? I.e. explain why mypy does not report an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 type check not works with use typing module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976861/python-3-type-check-not-works-with-use-typing-module)

Comment: ye @MahmoudFarouq is right

Comment: @MahmoudFarouq, the question you mention does not explain why mypy does not report an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s because — unfortunately! — booleans in Python are integers. As in, `bool` is a subclass of `int`:

```
In [1]: issubclass(bool, int)
Out[1]: True
```

Hence the code typechecks, and `False` is a valid integer with value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are right:

From the docs (contents of test.py):

```
class C2:
    def __init__(self, arg: int):
        self.var = arg


c2 = C2(True)
c2 = C2('blah')

mypy test.py
$>test.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "C2" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source

Commenting the c2 = C2('blah')

```
class C2:
    def __init__(self, arg: int):
        self.var = arg


c2 = C2(True)

mypy test.py

Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Seems like Booleans are taken as integers for some reason
And the explanation:
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1757

which means

```
class C2:
def __init__(self, arg: bool):
    self.var = arg

# tHIx WORKS FINE
c2 = C2(true)
# tHIx DOES NOT WORK
c2 = C2(0)
```

test.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "C2" has incompatible type "int"; expected "bool"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)