# Pycharm static type checker fails

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

maybe someone can help me out here.
I have been struggling for a long time with this static type checker that pycharm integrated.

Some Specs:

- Python 3.7.7
- Windows 10 Pro x64

I tried on following PyCharm versions.

- Professional 2020.1.3
- Community 2020.2.3

I tried to illustrate the problem. You can copy & paste it into your PyCharm to verify the issue.

```
class SpecificCLS:
    pass


class CLS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.integer: int = 0
        self.specific_cls: SpecificCLS = SpecificCLS()

    def set_im_int(self, value: int):
        self.integer = value

    def get_im_int(self) -> int:
        return self.integer

    def get_specific_cls(self) -> SpecificCLS:
        return self.specific_cls

    def set_specific_cls(self, value: SpecificCLS):
        self.specific_cls = value


cls = CLS()

# Example for assigning a class into an integer
cls.integer = SpecificCLS()  # PyCharm does NOT show any error/warning that a class is assigned into an variable that is declared as an "int"
cls.set_im_int(SpecificCLS())  # PyCharm recognise an error (underlined red): Expected type 'int', got 'SpecificCLS' instead

# Example for assigning an integer into a class
cls.specific_cls = 1  # PyCharm does NOT show any error/warning that a class is assigned into an variable that is declared as an "int"
cls.set_specific_cls(1)  # PyCharm recognise an error (underlined red): Expected type 'SpecificCLS', got 'int' instead
```

[PyCharm Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdh9w.png)

If you look into this line you will notice that there is no error shown.

```
cls.integer = SpecificCLS()  # PyCharm does NOT show any error/warning that a class is assigned into an variable that is declared as an "int"
```

If we use a setter method to assign the value, pycharm is recognizing the wrong assingment correctly.

```
cls.set_im_int(SpecificCLS())  # PyCharm recognise an error (underlined red): Expected type 'int', got 'SpecificCLS' instead
```

So can anyone tell me why the type checking for setter works just fine but the other assignments don't?

So far i have always used the getter/setter to verify that i will assign the right types to eachother. Therefore i marked the fields private with '__' so that no one can change the state directly.
Since i have updated from python 3.5.x to 3.7.x i thought that i can remove this boilderplate code. I'd like to have that static type checking functionality but i don't like to force me into using getter/setter all the time.

I appreciate your help.

Best Regards

**Update 18.11.2020: 12:00**
Sorry for the misleading example. I have tried to edit the snipped and hope that the issue is clear now. I also tried to explain in more detail what problem i see in this execution/performance of pycharm. I added a updated screenshot as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mypy doesn't throw an error when mixing booleans with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973631/mypy-doesnt-throw-an-error-when-mixing-booleans-with-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Sylvaus i figured out what the problem was and found a solution for it.

PyCharm does not recognize the violation of [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) but mypy does it correctly!
Install the Mypy plugin via

File -> Settings -> Plugins

If you run mypy it will tell you that there are errors now. BUT it takes some time until pycharms analyser is triggered and display the result of mypy.

I will try to bind the analyser to code format shortcut. I will update this post if im able to do it.

**Edit:**
Thanks to [user2235698](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235698/user2235698) here is the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889) from jetbrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889

Comment: It is not true, PEP 526 is supported by PyCharm since 2016 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20744), annotate your attributes on the class level and all expected warnings will be raised.

Comment: @user2235698 Why does it not recognize the violation in the example above? Why i should use class variable instead of instance variable?

Comment: It won't be a class variable, example: `class MyClass: integer: int`, it will be a class-level annotation

Comment: Hm. I tried it out and still no warning with the PyCharm typechecker. Mypy does show me the warning.

Comment: Sorry, you are right: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889

Comment: I can not upvote your comment for issue reference. :( I guess i have not enought rep to do it. But nevertheless imaginary +1 from me.

Comment: Please vote for the issue then (thumbs up near the title) :) Votes are considered in issues prioritization.

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm and mypy are both right because bool derives from int and by indicating that you want an int, you accept any variable which type derives from int.

You can verify that bool derives from int by doing `issubclass(bool, int)`

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I updated my question based on your clarification.